# C++ infinite loop

Tags: c++, while-loop

I am attempting to write a loop that will repeat until the user enters one of the correct choices (either 1 or 0).  For some reason when I have the loop written as below it creates an infinite loop.

I am intending for the loop to only execute while control is not 0 OR not 1, but for some reason it will always execute and becomes an infinite loop.

```
cout<<"Please enter 1 for another customer or 0 to quit : ";
cin>>control;

  while ((control != 0 )|| (control != 1))
    { 
      cout<<"Invalid Entry! Please enter a 1 to enter another customer or 0 to quit: ";
      cin>>control;
    }
```

I changed it to be while control less than 0 OR greater than 1, which works but I am still confused as to why the other loop is not working.

Comment: What is the data type of `control` Check http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/fail/

Answer (score 4):

You have to use && operator.

```
while ((control != 0 ) && (control != 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(control != 0) || (control != 1)
```

is equivalent to,

```
!(control == 0 && control == 1)
```

but,

```
(control == 0 && control == 1)
```

is always false (there is no such number).

Therefore, the whole expression will always get true value.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to break out

```
while ((control != 0 )|| (control != 1))
```

is

```
!(control != 0) && !(control != 1)
```

which is equivalent to

```
control == 0 && control == 1
```

which is impossible for all integers.